# How to confirm it's a valid pdf and find cdf?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

$$\text{Let X be a continuous random variable with pdf}$$

$$f(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      0 & x\leq 0 \\
      \frac{x}{100}  e^{\frac{-x^2}{200}}& x > 0 \\
   \end{cases}
$$

$$\text{(a) Confirm that f(x) is a valid pdf. Hint: substitute u = } x^2/200$$
$$\text{(b) Calculate }P(X \leq 20), \text{ and } P(10 \leq X \leq 20)$$
$$\text{(c) Give an expression (not an integral!) for } P(X \leq x), \text{ the cdf of }X$$

Comment: For (a) Show $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx = 1$ and $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pdf must meet the following criteria:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx = 1$$
$$ f(x) \geq 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

It's trivial to show that $f(x) \geq 0$. So, taking $f(x)$ as the function above.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x) dx + \int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x}{100}e^{-x^2/200} dx$$

Substitute $u=-x^2/200$ and $du=-x/100$

$$-\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^u du = \left.-e^{-x^2/200}\right\rvert_{0}^{\infty} = 1 $$

The CDF can be calculated by

$$ F(x) = P( X \leq x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(x) dx = 
\begin{cases}
0, \ \text{if} \ x \leq 0\\
1 -e^{-x^2/200}, \ \text{if} \ x > 0
\end{cases} $$

Exercise $(b)$ is easy to solve using $F(x)$. Notice $P(10 \leq X \leq 20) = F(20) - F(10)$